# Exclude widget from scrolling in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web, scroll, stack

I was looking for design inspiration for my website and came across a very interesting design, [this one](https://preview.webflow.com/preview/dynamic-studios?preview=2640ed4b667a6ccbc9e7f3a082dfab69) *(in web view)*.

What intrigued me, was how the brand name text (DYNAMIC STUDIOS) kept its static position, while the rest of the "widgets" -both in front and behind the text- were included in the scrolling.

My question is: how could we implement this feature with Flutter?

If we only had items in front or behind the Text, then with a simple Stack and SingleChildScrollView that could have easily been done. But how can you "Stack" an item in between "a scroll view"?

---

*Showcased Website was found from the article [12 unique examples of photography portfolio websites](https://webflow.com/blog/photography-portfolio-websites).*

Comment: Check parallax effect in flutter, it a starting point.

Comment: Was unaware of this effect! I will check it out, thanks!